# nodeJS + Swig template passing variable to javascript

Tags: node.js, express, swig

Is there any way using express + swig template for nodeJS to pass variables from the server side to client side javascript? I know it can be done in Jade but I'd rather stick with a template engine that more closely resembles HTML. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 11):

OK I will assume that you could configure your express with consolidate.swig if not please read this link (http://tinyurl.com/kcs8kvy).
Well I didn't find the direct way to pass variable values to client javascript but I have found a workaround.

for instance you're sending an object, in your route at express:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  var myUser = { name: "Obama" };
  res.render("index", {user: myUser});
});
```

then in your index.html file you can create a script tag:

`<html>`

```
<body>
<script>
  var username = "{{user.name}}";
</script>

<script src="whatever.js"></script>
</body>
```

`</html>`

and then in your whatever.js file the username variable will be available with its correct value. I hope that this help you.

Comment: how to handle complex json array iteration !

Comment: when,I am doing only {{user}} iam getting [object object] but when i do json.stringify on server it gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &" even after {{user|json_encode }}

Answer (score 2):

To pass json objects from backend server to the template you can do:

***var data = {{jsonData|raw|json}}***