# How to set JSON object in variable using swig node js?

Tags: node.js, express, swig

I want to set a JSON object in client side javascript using swig. I tried with json filter of swig but it just print JSON object not assign. `<script type="text/javascript">
var bootstrap = "{{locals.bootstrap | json}}"</script>` as we know in Javascript this bootstrap variable is globally accessible in whole the application. but I am not able to set JSON object. I tried this `var bootstrap = "{{locals.bootstrap}}"` [refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617065/nodejs-swig-template-passing-variable-to-javascript/18819253#18819253) . but its for just any property not for json object, its just set "[object,object]" in bootstrap not json object.  I tried with json filter of swig [refered link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448700/how-to-output-json-with-swig-in-nodejs) , but not get succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

var bootstrap = "{{bootstrap | json | safe}}"

Comment: No need to use "locals."

Comment: See meanjs source where user is set as a global variable in app/views/layout.server.view.html

Comment: <!--Embedding The User Object-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var user = {{ user | json | safe }};
 </script>

Comment: same result after removing "locals"

Comment: @ subin will you please share the link where from see

Comment: Make sure server is restarted after the change

Comment: Link https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/views/layout.server.view.html

Comment: the mistake I was doing it to use "{{bootstrap | json | safe}}" in string format. now json is displaying fine but throw an exception  unexpected token o.  I cross checked my json object it is ok